# Where to unzip Google APIs(x86 System Image)

Tags: android, sdk

I downloaded [this](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/google_apis_x86-19_r02.zip) manually since i was having slow speeds in sdk manager.

Now i cant figure out where to put the downloaded files.

I'm on Windows 8 and the downloaded file is,

> google_apis_x86-999428-linux-x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract it into the `Android-SDK` where you have kept your android sdk folder. In that you can extract it for the api level which you have downloaded at the path

```
   C:\..\android-sdks\system-images\android-19\x86\"Extract here"
```

Comment: should I extract the contents of that linux folder or the whole folder?

Comment: Extract the whole folder.

Comment: ok. if i've installed the intel x86 system images, is it necessary to install the google apis x86 and arm?

Comment: Not necessary. But it will be required whenever you are going to use the google api.

Comment: i've extracted the files as mentioned but sdk manager still shows not installed.

Comment: Check out link it might help you. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-4-4-kitkat-installation-instructions-manually

Comment: about the first link, i've already installed that. this one is Android x86 + Google APIs.